# Is there a way I can setup a PowerBI workspace to retrieve data from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I frequently use a PowerShell cmdlet ‘(Get-ACL).access’ to obtain details of which user groups have access to a windows shared drive. I then write other supplementary scripts to identify the users setup on those groups, along with their entitlements (read/write/delete) and throw them on a csv.

Whilst the process is quite straightforward, it is very manually intensive as the above steps have to be undertaken for each nas drive / shared folder.

Is there anyway I can link PowerShell to PowerBI to enable my non technical colleagues to simply enter the drive name as one of the parameters and get them the required data?

My online research shows that there are a number of articles talking about controlling a PowerBI workspace from PowerShell, but not the other way round.

Thanks!

Comment: Your PowerShell scripts should save these CSV files somewhere, where Power BI can access them. Schedule them to be executed daily/hourly/weekly/etc. Then use these CSV files as a source for a Power BI report.

Comment: That’s a useful concept for sure. The problem is that the code isn’t static, I.e. the path name will keep changing as there are lots of shared drives / folders that can be queried by the end user. I want a user to pass the folder name as a parameter on PowerBI , which should run the get-ACL cmdlet on PowerShell and return the output via PowerBI.

Comment: The folder name and drive should be stored in the CSV files.